# Need to show different logo in mobile and tablet devices

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, header

I am building an ecommerce site using this theme http://goo.gl/3BwG7R

I have changed the header to black and and have a light logo. When viewed on mobile and tablet  I need the header to be white (native) and the logo to be dark.

I have failed to utilize the media queries to make this happen.

The theme has 2 header files, the main file calls the other files to display stuff.

```
*** MAIN HEADER ------------------

<div id="logo" class="positionleft"><?php if_logo(); // print the logo html ?></div>

--------------------------------------------

*** SECOND HEADER (called header-functions) -----------------

// print the logo html
if(!function_exists("if_logo")){
function if_logo(){ 

        $logotype = if_get_option( THE_SHORTNAME . '_logo_type');
        $logoimage = if_get_option( THE_SHORTNAME . '_logo_image'); 
        $sitename =  if_get_option( THE_SHORTNAME . '_site_name');
        $tagline = if_get_option( THE_SHORTNAME . '_tagline');

        if($sitename=="") $sitename = get_bloginfo('name');
        if($tagline=="") $tagline = get_bloginfo('description'); 
        if($logoimage == "") $logoimage = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .            "/images/logo.png"; 
      ?>
        <?php if($logotype == 'textlogo'){ ?>

            <h1><a href="<?php echo home_url( '/'); ?>" title="<?php echo        esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', THE_LANG ) ); ?>"><?php echo $sitename; ?></a></h1><span        class="desc"><?php echo $tagline; ?></span>

        <?php } else { ?>

        <div id="logoimg">
        <a href="<?php echo home_url( '/' ) ; ?>" title="<?php echo $sitename; ?>" >
            <img src="<?php echo $logoimage ; ?>" alt="<?php echo $sitename; ?>" />
        </a>
        </div>

    <?php } ?>

     <?php 
  }
}

*** MAIN CSS --------------------------

#logo{margin-right:7px;padding:14px 10px ;}
#logo img{height:43px;}
#logo h1{margin-bottom:0px; letter-spacing:-1px;}
/* Menu */
#navigation{text-align:left;}
#topnav{
margin:0;
padding:0px 0 0 0px;
list-style-type:none;
overflow:visible;
position:relative;
float:right;

}

*** LAYOUT CSS ---------------------

   #logo{text-align:center;margin:0px;}
   #logoimg img{text-align:center;margin:0px auto; max-width:100%;}
```

Comment: So what media queries have you tried?

Comment: Are you using a mobile detect php script? if so then you can just assign `$logoimage` a path value leading to your mobile version

Comment: @ Ralph, I tried creating 2 logo classes #logo and #mobilelogo but did not know how to call the other logo in the header.

Comment: @ Vector I dont think there is a mobile detect php script in the theme. I have not found it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://codepen.io/thesublimeobject/pen/mKLzo) is a quick mark up of what it would look like to use media queries with img rather than using a background image. I used divs instead of images, but it's the same concept. If you minimize the browser you will see the text change.

Answer (score 0):

Use logo as a background with media query.

```
@media (min-width:769px){
    #logo{
        background-image: url(link/to/main/logo.png);
    }
}

@media (max-width:768px){
    #logo{
        background-image: url(link/to/tablet/logo.png);
    }
}

@media (max-width:480px){
    #logo{
        background-image: url(link/to/mobile/logo.png);
    }
}
```

Comment: While this solution will work, I think it is better to use <img> for a logo as it is an important part of the content of your site.

Comment: WebDevRun, if I use the background solution in media query do I kill the code in the header-functions file? How do I make it work with that file?